# AWS API Gateway: How to remove/replace query string parameter in HTTP Proxy Passthrough integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When I query my `Invoke URL` as `https://xxx.execute-api.yyy.amazonaws.com/test/q?apiKey=AAA` with my below setup my backend receives a call as `https://api.mysite.com/q?apiKey=AAA&apiKey=111`: one `apiKey=AAA` comes from the client, the second one - `apiKey=111` comes from the `Integration Request` configuration.

**Question**:
What/How should I configure an integration that `apiKey=AAA` either removed from the client call or replaced on the integration step with `111` value so that only one `apiKey` comes to the backend?

**Note**:

- with proxy passthrough integration the Mapping Templates are not available;
- the reason for such configuration is that my legacy backend has a big amount of endpoints which is not possible to configure individually.

**My setup**:

- I have created a new REST API.
- Then I have created a new Configure as a Proxy resource named `proxy` with a Resource Path `/{proxy+}` with the following setup for `ANY` method as a proxy integration:

  - Integration type `HTTP Proxy`
  - Endpoint URL: `https://api.mysite.com/{proxy}`
  - Content Handling: `Passthrough`
- As a next step, I have configured an `Integration Request` for my `/{proxy+} - ANY` by adding a new query string to the `URL Query String Parameters` section:

  - Name: `myApiKey`
  - Mapped from: `'111'`
- Then I click `Deploy API` to `test` stage and getting `Invoke URL`, let's say: `https://xxx.execute-api.yyy.amazonaws.com/test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with Proxy Integration, we can still override Request & Response.
[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/overriding-request-response-parameters-and-response-status-in-amazon-api-gateway/) is the blog. Let me try to summarize.

- Ensure that `Use Proxy Integration` is unchecked
- Simple VTL template in Mapping Template to replace `apiKey` queryParameter.

> ```
>   #set($newApiKey = "abcd")
>   $input.json("$")
>   #set($context.requestOverride.querystring.apiKey = $newApiKey)
> ```

- Add Method Responses example response codes 200, 400 and 500.
- Add Integration Response for each status code for each response codes for example http status for 2xx `2\d{2}` with pass through behaviour.

Lets say we have a `proxy` setup for path `/someapi/sompath`. Above template will replace `/someapi/sompath?apiKey=100` to `{proxy}?apiKey=abcd`

Comment: The replacement works, but this approach brings a lot of problems as it requires to do a lot of configuration in `Method Response` and `Integration Response` even for delivering CORS headers back to the client, as according to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) for the ANY method in a proxy integration, any applicable CORS headers will not be set. Same for Content-Type which is not always json. Please, advise what should I do to deliver all headers through `Integration Response` from the back-end to the client with less effort.

Comment: For a proxy integration, we can't make any changes to `Method Response` or `Integration Response`.  The change in this answer is for `Integration Request`.  and Response from backend is sent to client without changes and we don't need to do any setup for it and we can't alter response headers. And to handle CORS, we need to add OPTIONS method, with MOCK integration and return necessary headers back in `Integration Response`, leaving 'ANY` as is.

Comment: If I leave an `Integration Response` chain untouched after removing a `Use Proxy Integration` flag in `Integration Request` THEN I receive the following error: `Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured. Endpoint Response Status Code: 200`. So, unchecked `Use Proxy Integration` affects to response chain as well.

Comment: Ok. I tested it out,  it looks like we needed to setup Response as well.  1. setup Method response 2. Setup Integration Response. I will update my answer.

Comment: @vaa , overall yes, overriding `Integration Request` does seem to affect `Integration Response`, which is weird.

Comment: Thanks for the help. To sum up, your proposed solution does overwrite. All other required steps are weird from my perspective. Accepted!